# ATTINY 85 - use host laptop's internet

Tags: attiny, attiny85

Suppose I enable USB tethering (internet) on my laptop. Will it be possible to use that internet on an ATTINY 85 connected to USB.

Comment: no, the processing power of the microcontroller is insufficient ... your laptop has to act as a gateway between a serial port and the internet

Comment: Since there are uncounted applications for an internet connection, what specifically do you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

No, the attiny85 is simply too slow and not powerful enough to process your laptop's internet connection and begin something with it. If you only have to make API Request, you can hard code them into the firmware, and send the api-request-string to your computer, make your computer execute the API-request and then send the API response from the computer to the attiny to process the response there.

Regards

Dario